# SimpleXML: How to read XML content as list?

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

Assume we have this xml input:

```
<list>
   <id>1</id>
   <id>2</id>
   <id>3</id>
</list>
```

How can can I decode the id-content into a list? Like this:

```
 @ElementList
 List<Integer> ids;
```

This doesn't work, it seems `@ElementList` only works for attributes.Is there an other way to achive it?

Comment: The SimpleXml tag shows that it is about a PHP library...

Comment: simplexml is also a java lib -> http://simple.sourceforge.net/maven.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using *inline* and *entry* on the @ElementList annotation

```
@ElementList(entry = "id", inline = true, required = false)
List<Integer> ids;
```